# MariaDB password reset not working

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, mariadb

I am running `MariaDB` and i am trying to reset password but its not working.

```
[root@osdial-99a8c941 ~]# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
[1] 11125
```

Next set password:

```
[root@osdial-99a8c941 ~]# mysql -u root
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 1
Server version: 5.5.37-MariaDB-wsrep-log MariaDB Stylite Build (GPL), wsrep_25.10.r3980

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, Monty Program Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql;
MariaDB [mysql]> update user set password=PASSWORD("new-password") where User='root';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [mysql]> select * from user;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

If you look `user` table is still empty :(

Even i tried to create account but got following error:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> CREATE USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new-password';
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

What i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` is needed to load the password table.  Do this after the `UPDATE` or `GRANT`.

See the [User manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html).  (MariaDB and MySQL should be identical in this area.)

Comment: actually, this should be done *after* the `update` or `grant` as it flushes the in memory cache, and reloads the privileges from the table. [Per MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html)

Comment: Belatedly fixed Answer to align with Matt's comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't fix it, here is commands I used and it fixed pass not working mysql, after commands you can put your own password.

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https curl

curl -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc 'https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc'

sh -c "echo 'deb https://mirrors.xtom.com/mariadb/repo/10.8/debian bullseye main' >>/etc/apt/sources.list"

apt-get update

apt-get install mariadb-server
```